# Difference between byte and uint8 datatypes in solidity

Tags: solidity, data-types

I want to understand if there is a difference between byte data-type and uint8 in solidity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runtime-wise, they are identical.

Compilation-wise, they are different:

- You cannot use arithmetic operations on `byte` operands
- You cannot assign numerical constants to `byte` variables

For example, instead of doing this:

```
uint8 x = 1;
uint8 y = 2;
uint8 z = x + y;
```

You need to do this:

```
byte x = byte(uint8(1));
byte y = byte(uint8(2));
byte z = byte(uint8(x) + uint8(y));
```